# Regressing a discrete variable

Tags: regression, time-series, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model

I have a discrete dependent variable (say, number of units bought) and want to run a linear regression with in-store promotion, seasonality, trend etc. as predictor variables. I'm not sure if it is feasible to run a regression on a discrete variable. Till now I have been using a continuous variable as the dependent variable in regression. If valid, what are the nuances and caveats I need to be aware of?

Comment: Lots of threads here on Poisson and other kinds of count regression. I'm deleting the "normal distribution" tag. It won't help anyone interested in this thread.

Answer (score 6):

One of the tags supplied to your question says it all: generalized-linear-model. There are several options here. Since your response is a positive count, a Poisson regression might work. The negative binomial is another option. In most software, these models are set up to look like basic linear regression -- you supply predictors to the response in the usual way -- and up to a point, the models have a similar interpretation.  Under the hood, the math is different. Regression diagnostics can also be tricky.

If your count variable takes on a large number of discrete values, you can probably treat it as continuous. A log transformation might produce better looking residuals. Or not. It's worth trying some transformations to see if you get a better fit.

If you do venture into the realm of generalized linear models, I would suggest first reading an introductory text on the subject. [Hardin's book](http://www.amazon.ca/Generalized-Linear-Models-Extensions-Third/dp/1597181056/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1424871711&sr=1-5&keywords=generalized%20linear%20models) is nice, but oriented towards using Stata. McCullagh and Nelder is the classic text, but the math is advanced and the cost is high.

RE: nuances and caveats. Plotting residuals seldom produces illuminating results. Fitting the models involves an iterative optimization routine ... so check that your solution converged properly. p-values from likelihood ratio tests are based on asymptotic chi-squared tests. So while these models look like linear regression models, the results are never quite as trustworthy. Check the model against a holdout set.

Comment: In general, when trying to design an analysis, do you always need to specify the distribution of the variables?